# Scrapy-Splash: Failed to run docker container with scrapinghub/splash:latest as base image

Tags: python, docker, scrapy, azureservicebus, scrapy-splash

Am building a python Scrapy application which uses some Azure Services and Scrapy-Splash. I tried creating a docker image for my application with `scrapinghub/splash:latest` as base image in my local windows machine.
Below is the Dockerfile am using,

```
FROM scrapinghub/splash:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/snapshot

ADD requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD . ./

EXPOSE 8888 80

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/snapshot/init_container.sh"]
```

The *init_container.sh* file has the statement to run the application, `python /usr/src/snapshot/SiteCrawler.py`.
Now when I run the docker image with the command `docker run testsnapshot:0.1`, the application starts and stops due to import error, **ImportError: No module named azure.servicebus**

I tried creating a docker image of the application with python:3.6.6 as base image, it works fine.

The application build the docker image and installs the packages from requirements.txt correctly. 
Attaching below my requirements.txt content

```
asn1crypto==0.24.0
attrs==18.2.0
Automat==0.7.0
azure-common==1.1.16
azure-nspkg==3.0.2
azure-servicebus==0.21.1
azure-storage==0.36.0
certifi==2018.10.15
cffi==1.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==2.3.1
cssselect==1.0.3
hyperlink==18.0.0
idna==2.7
incremental==17.5.0
lxml==4.2.5
parsel==1.5.0
pip==18.0
pyasn1==0.4.4
pyasn1-modules==0.2.2
pycparser==2.19
PyDispatcher==2.0.5
PyHamcrest==1.9.0
pyOpenSSL==18.0.0
python-dateutil==2.7.3
queuelib==1.5.0
requests==2.20.0
Scrapy==1.5.1
scrapy-splash==0.7.2
service-identity==17.0.0
setuptools==39.0.1
six==1.11.0
Twisted==16.1.1
urllib3==1.24
w3lib==1.19.0
zope.interface==4.5.0
```

Comment: Got it worked. Just added `VOLUME ["/usr/src/snapshot"]` to Docker file. But now I face a different issue where the splash url is not accessible from my scrapy. I tried with `http://127.0.0.1:8050` and `http://0.0.0.0:8050`

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Just had to add the *WORKDIR /usr/src/snapshot* to **VOLUME** as below.

```
VOLUME ["/usr/src/snapshot"]
```